# How to split point cloud into cells

Tags: python, coordinates, point-clouds

I'm trying to do NDT cells.
So I want to split my point cloud into cube groups size s. Of course, I can randomly choose one point and check other points if d(x1, x2) < s, but how can i optimize it(e.g. with NumPy)?

Comment: I think, that I cane divide every point coordinates on s, and it will be coordinate of it cube

Answer (score 2):

Every cube must have size/volume s^3, right?
Do you want to build a relation `(x,y,z) -> CubeOf(x,y,z)`, that is every point is related to a special cube?

I would iterate over point coordinates and map every point to appropriate cell:

you can use MODULO:

```
cx := x % s
cy := x % s
cz := x % s
```

Where `cx, cy, cz` is pseudo coordinates of one cube, which you the point `(x, y, z)` map on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a extensive work about The Three-Dimensional Normal-Distributions Transform:

https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:276162/FULLTEXT02.pdf

If you only ask, if a point p1 is in cell or not, you don't need d(p1, p2). You just need the coordinates of p1 and the cell size. But it's my naive opinion. Just read the paper.

Comment: Actually, now I'm trying to code NDT-RANSAC, and I'm just not sure, that I'm doing it in a right way. Thank you! I'll try to find something here.

Comment: @xufana I'm not so strong in mathematics but I could try to help with implementation. Do you already have a init project where one can contribute (maybe on GitHub)?

Comment: yes, https://github.com/xufana/RANSAC.git here and @xufana telegram